# Passing Variable from R to LaTeX

Tags: pdfpages, r, knitr

Consider a variable in `R`, say

```
YEAR <- 2000
```

I have various files whose names are dependent on this year, say `YEAR 1.pdf`, `YEAR 2.pdf`.

Is there a way for me to pass this variable into a `.rnw` which includes the `\includepdf` function as follows in LaTeX and compile the .pdf? e.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf{YEAR + " 1.pdf"}
\includepdf{YEAR + " 2.pdf"}
\end{document}
```

where `YEAR` is the variable pulled from `R`, and `+` denotes concatenation of strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what is `\Sexpr{...}` for.  Just remember that in TeX you do not need a special operation for concatenation.

As an example, I created two files, `fig1.pdf` and `fig2.pdf`.  Here is my `.rnw` file

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
number <- 1
@ 
\includegraphics{fig\Sexpr{number}.pdf}
<<>>=
number <- 2
@ 
\includegraphics{fig\Sexpr{number}.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The corresponding `tex` fragment after knitting.  `\Sexpr{number}` is substituted for the R expression result:

```
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{alltt}
\hlstd{number} \hlkwb{<-} \hlnum{1}
\end{alltt}
\end{kframe}
\end{knitrout}
\includegraphics{fig1.pdf}
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{alltt}
\hlstd{number} \hlkwb{<-} \hlnum{2}
\end{alltt}
\end{kframe}
\end{knitrout}
\includegraphics{fig2.pdf}
```

[image]

The last note: please do **not** use space in file names:  TeX is easily confused.  Better to have `YEAR_1.pdf`, `YEAR_2.pdf` etc than `YEAR 1.pdf`, `YEAR 2.pdf` etc.