# How to replace a string in \Sexpr by a variable

Tags: r

I am using latex to automate reports.  In R, I create a data frame that contains all of the metrics and then using `\Sexpr` I filter that data frame for a specific metric.  Currently, I have this:

```
\Sexpr{df$var1[df$var2 == 'metric1']}
```

Is it possible to save "metric1" as a variable so that in each section I can just call it once?

For example:

```
foo1 = metric1
\Sexpr{df$var1[df$var2 == foo1]}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Doesn't your `R` code ALREADY let you call the value of `metric1`?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't word it properly.  The problem isn't with R but to be able to store "metric1" as a variable in Latex and call it in \sexpr.

Comment: Why not just store it as a variable in `R` (as you have above) and when you need it in LaTeX, just use `\Sexpr`? See, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362119/passing-variable-from-r-to-latex

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply need to quote what you're doing.  You can do something like:

```
<<mycodechunk>>=
foo1 = "metric1"
@
```

Then somewhere in the Sweave document:

```
\Sexpr{df$var1[df$var2 == foo1]}
```

or probably:

```
\Sexpr{df$var1[df$var2 == foo1,]}
```